# Standard library usage as a limiter, unclear example

Tags: discussion

I was looking through some contests when I found [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/debunking-stroustrups-debunking-of-the-myth-c-is-for-large-complicated-pro). There was a rather long discussion concerning using boost/asio in a web parsing contest.

The post was meant to debunk a long (by golf standards) piece of code in C++. However, the example code could not be posted as an answer, as the example itself used boost/asio and the contest stated no third party libraries could be used.

Should libraries that are considered to be standard by the community, even if they aren't necessarily deemed standard by the language creators still be considered third-party?

Should example code in posts have to be viable as an answer?

Comment: For the last point: The purpose of example code to me is to be able to verify *accuracy* of answers. So no, I don't think it needs to be viable as an answer, as long as the behavior is correct.

Comment: Also, very related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188/14215